# Freyd's algebraic real analysis, scale and linear order

Tags: real-analysis, category-theory, foundations, monoidal-categories

I have been studying [Freyd's algebraic theory of the reals](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/20/10/20-10.pdf) in the past week. I have problems understanding his linear representation theorem (Theorem 8.1) that every scale can be embedded in a product of linear scales. To wit, I have two problems:

1. I thought that scale was linearly ordered under the relation of partial order defined by $a \multimap b = \top$ (top here should be the \top of tautology). So the embedding should be trivial.
2. In the proof, he shows that the meet $y \vee x$ is strictly smaller than $\top$ in a scale that is a SDI (an algebra is a SDI "if whenever it is embedded into a product of algebras one of the coordinate
   maps is itself an embedding"). This I understand. But he also says that from this follows the disjonction property $x \multimap y  \vee y \multimap x = \top$ in a SDI scale. Now, I can't see how this follows.

Thank you for your help,

Jeff.

Comment: Ok I understand now. I got confused with the remark about internalization. The equation of linearity  $x \multimap y  \vee y \multimap x = \top$ is the internalization and the sum is the operation in a lattice not a disjonction. I also see how the sum $x \vee y$ being in the SDI scale, whenever $x$ and $y$ are, imply the disjonction property and hence linearity as an order.